# Limit involving log and exponential

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I show that the following is true?

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{(2 n+1) /(2 n)} \log \left(\frac{a}{n}+1\right)=a$$

I have tried using the L'Hôpital's rule since $\log \left(\frac{a}{n}+1\right)$ tends to zero, but the derivative of
$1/n^{(2 n+1) /(2 n)}$ is not very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write
\begin{eqnarray*} n^{(2 n+1) /(2 n)} \log \left(\frac{a}{n}+1\right)
& = & \sqrt{n^{\frac 1n}} \log \left(\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^{n}\right) \\
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} & \sqrt 1 \cdot \log \left(e^a\right) = a
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$n^{(2n+1)/2n}=n (n^{1/2n})$ and $n^{1/2n} \to 1$. So you only have to show that $n \log (\frac an +1) \to a$ which can be proved by applying L'Hopital's Rule to limit of  $\frac {\log (ax+1)} x$ as $x \to 0$ .